# Const self-referential structures

Tags: c, struct, constants, self-reference

I'm writing in C.

I've defined a new type (noFunc_menuEntry) which is made of a self-referential structure.

```
struct noFunc_menuEntry_tag {
    const char *text;
    struct noFunc_menuEntry_tag *up_entry;
    struct noFunc_menuEntry_tag *down_entry;
    struct noFunc_menuEntry_tag *back_entry;
    struct noFunc_menuEntry_tag *enter_entry;
};
typedef struct noFunc_menuEntry_tag noFunc_menuEntry;
```

I need to define a series of variable like this:

```
menuEntry_1 = {title_1, &menuEntry_2, &menuEntry_4, &menuEntry_1, &menuEntry_5};
menuEntry_2 = {title_2, &menuEntry_3, &menuEntry_1, &menuEntry_1, &menuEntry_6};
```

and so on.

So i need to separate declaration and defition of the variable, because every variable depends on other variables. In an header file i've written the declaration

```
noFunc_menuEntry menuEntry_1, menuEntry_2, menuEntry_3, menuEntry_4, menuEntry_5, menuEntry_6;
```

etc..., and in a .c file in a function i've initialized the variables:

```
void menu_init(void)
{
        menuEntry_1.text = title;
        menuEntry_1.up_entry = &menuEntry_2
}
```

and so on for the other members and variables.

However i want my variables to be `const`:

```
const noFunc_menuEntry menuEntry_1, menuEntry_2, menuEntry_3, menuEntry_4, menuEntry_5, menuEntry_6;
```

So my question is about separing declaration and definition of `const` variables of the type i've defined. How can i do? Am i doing something wrong?

Naturally if i simply add `const` in the declaration, the compiler report me an error when i initialize the variables (i'm trying to write read-only variables).

Comment: If you already init the variables with `menuEntry_1 = {title_1, &menuEntry_2, &menuEntry_4, &menuEntry_1, &menuEntry_5};`, why would you initialize them again in `menu_init`?

Comment: Since your struct contains *pointers* to these (global) variables, I believe you should be able to simply define them and initialize in a single line, i.e. there is no need to have functions for initialization. It's true that *"every variable depends on other variables"*, but if you are changing `menuEntry_1` contents, it doesn't mean `&menuEntry_1` will change.

Comment: @user694733 : I initialize the variables in `menu_init` if i don't use them as a `const`, but if they have to be a `const` naturally i don't use `menu_init`. I was looking for the right way to do it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want these variables to be `const`, then you must do the initialization without the function.

But first, let's handle the `const` in type definition:

```
typedef struct noFunc_menuEntry_tag noFunc_menuEntry;
struct noFunc_menuEntry_tag {
    const char *text;
    const noFunc_menuEntry *up_entry;
    const noFunc_menuEntry *down_entry;
    const noFunc_menuEntry *back_entry;
    const noFunc_menuEntry *enter_entry;
};
```

Then the declarations for the header file:

```
extern const noFunc_menuEntry menuEntry_1;
extern const noFunc_menuEntry menuEntry_2;
 ...
```

And finally the definition and initialization in source file:

```
const noFunc_menuEntry menuEntry_1 = {title_1, &menuEntry_2, &menuEntry_4, &menuEntry_1, &menuEntry_5};
const noFunc_menuEntry menuEntry_2 = {title_2, &menuEntry_3, &menuEntry_1, &menuEntry_1, &menuEntry_6};
 ...
```

Answer (score 6):

You could [use an array](http://ideone.com/JgZ0W4), since a bunch of `item_i` implies you may need to.

```
typedef struct noFunc_menuEntry_tag {
    const char *text;
    const struct noFunc_menuEntry_tag *up_entry;
    const struct noFunc_menuEntry_tag *down_entry;
    const struct noFunc_menuEntry_tag *back_entry;
    const struct noFunc_menuEntry_tag *enter_entry;
} noFunc_menuEntry;


int main(void) {
    const noFunc_menuEntry menuEntry[4] = {
        {"", &menuEntry[0], &menuEntry[1], &menuEntry[2], &menuEntry[3]},   
        {"", &menuEntry[0], &menuEntry[1], &menuEntry[2], &menuEntry[3]},   
        {"", &menuEntry[0], &menuEntry[1], &menuEntry[2], &menuEntry[3]},   
        {"", &menuEntry[0], &menuEntry[1], &menuEntry[2], &menuEntry[3]},   
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a clean way to do this task.

Answer (score 1):

Use `extern const` in the declaration in the header. `extern` will only declare the variable for use in the program, without allocating any memory.
Then proceed with defining it in the main
`const noFunc_menuEntry menuEntry_1 = {title_1, &menuEntry_2, &menuEntry_4, &menuEntry_1, &menuEntry_5}; .. so on`